# Navitage to tag underneath cursor using Ctrl ] for a bibtex entry

Tags: vim, latex, tex, ctags, bibtex

I have generated a tags file of a `.bib` bibliography file (referenced in a `.tex` file) and lines containing bibkeys in the `.bib` file such as the following correctly identify the bibkeys as tags.

`@Article{abc123,` and `@InBook{def123&233,`

The `.tex` file that utilizes these bibkeys is always structured so:

`\cite{abc123}` or `\cite{def123&233}`

That is, the bibkeys are always used within `{` and `}`.

While cursor is under `abc123`, pressing `Ctrl]` successfully navigates to that line in the `.bib` file. However, when the cursor is on `def123`, pressing `Ctrl]` returns an error because VIM tries to jump to tag `def123` which is not generated. The tag generated is only for the whole set of characters between `{` and `,` which is `def123&233` in this example -- the entire bibkey. Is there a way to have VIM correctly navigate tags that contain `&`? That is, while jumping to a tag, the tag to be considered may very well contain `&`.

Currently, my workaround is to visually select in the inner of `{` via `vi{` and then press `Ctrl]` or `g]` from within the `.tex` file where these references are cited.

I tried to map this sequence of keypresses to a keyboard shortcut via

`nmap <leader>t vi{ <C-]>`

but this sequence of key presses does not seem to be captured by this mapping and the `.bib` file is not navigated to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim lets you decide what constitutes a keyword character with `:help 'iskeyword'`:

```
:set iskeyword+=&     " a literal &
:set iskeyword+=38    " OR a decimal &
```

That option is used for `<C-]>` but also for many other features, so YMMV.

Since your problem is with `.tex` files (`plaintex` filetype by default) you should set that option only in that context. This is best done in a dedicated filetype plugin:

```
" in after/ftplugin/plaintex.vim
setlocal iskeyword+=&
```